# Metre(s) in Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, sanskrit, vishnu-sahasranama

Are different poetic metres used in the Mahabharata?  In particular, are the Bhagavad Gita and Vishnu Sahasranama in the same metre as the rest of the Mahabharata?